# Hibernate Spatial + Postgis + Geotools - Falha na persistência

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, postgis

Estou com um problema para persistir um dado geométrico no banco de dados (Postgres) dei uma lida nos foruns e documentação e não encontrei nada sobre isso, alguém pode me dar uma ajuda?

Libs:

pom.xml com as versões

```
<hibernate.envers.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.envers.version>
<hibernate.spatial.version>4.3.1-52N</hibernate.spatial.version> 
<hibernate.validator>4.3.2.Final</hibernate.validator> 
<hibernate.em.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.em.version>
```

Propriedade da entidade

```
@Column(name="the_geom" , columnDefinition = "Geometry", nullable = true) 
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
private Geometry theGeom;
```

Erro:

> Não pode inferir um tipo SQL a ser usado para uma instância de
>   `org.postgis.PGgeometry`. Use `setObject()` com um valor de Types
>   explícito para especificar o tipo a ser usado.

Answer (score 1):

Você configurou a propriedade "spring.jpa.database-platform" para PostgisDialect no seu Application.properties?

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
```

Answer (score 0):

Onde eu trabalho realizamos a persistência do theGeom utilizando o sql native. Veja um exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO st_teste (the_geom) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText(#conteudoTheGeo));
```

E no banco o tipo do campo está mapeado como *public.geometry*.

Comment: Eu gostaria de utilizar a lib do hibernate spatial para fazer a  persistência, consegui até fazer a persistência depois de ter criado um projeto novo com as mesmas dependências inclusive, mas não consigo fazer na minha aplicação porque aponta esse erro. Mas obrigado, pode ser uma boa alternativa.

Comment: Bacana Diego. Recentemente tiramos o hibernate da aplicação. Quando encontrar a solução, poste aqui! :)

Comment: Utilizei o que você sugeriu, mas estou tentando descobrir o motivo, assim que conseguir posto sim!